# excel count sets of dates that date is between

Tags: excel

Here is my data model: I have an excel sheet with each row representing a date range (an event). There is significant overlap. A2 might be 4/10/15, and B2 might be 4/12/15; while A3 might be 4/11/15 and B3 might be 4/12/15.
I am trying to get a count for each day of the year 2015 how many events occurred on that date. with my limited "for instance" I would get something like:

```
4/9/15    0
4/10/15   1
4/11/15   2
4/12/15   2
4/13/15   0
```

I have some sudo code for this if I were to just save the set as a csv and use java or something to grab each date and create an object but I find it hard to believe that excel is not capable of this on it's own.

We tried a wild number of countif and countifs statements but I am really just at a loss when it comes to excel.

I thought I was close with this:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A2,AND(Sheet2!A2>=(dates!B*), Sheet2!A2<=(dates!C*)))
```

but in order to get that to work I would need it to iterate through each row of dates and I am just not sure how to do that.

Any help is appreciated. As a backup plan I am refining my sudo-code for a possible vb excel script (never done that before) or just breaking it out into java and using the old text edit scripts I haven't had to touch since college labs.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your keyword is `COUNTIFS`

Say your criteria day is in cell `Sheet2!A2` and your event ranges are in sheet `Dates` columns B and C; Try this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(Dates!B:B, "<="&Sheet2!A2, Dates!C:C, ">="&Sheet2!A2)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you for sharing your knowledge.